# django blog views.py "method" member function definition, not sure where it is defined or where it takes me to

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, pycharm

[all process depicted pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZgwH.jpg)

I am finding it difficult to get a hold on some Django concepts, using pycharm and learning from Django by example by packt publishing on it's blog project I am trying to find where everything i use is basically coming from since im unsure of what methods come from main libraries just yet

I am having problem with this .method impementation, when i try goto > definition a whole bunch of possibilities pop up, since all have the f icon i presume these are just funcions, so i go to the lowest one which looks like the most serious one and directs me to QHttPRequestHeader.py   def method(self)

from my imports i can see that im not using this header, i know i could be indirectly using an import through indirect linking but I yet have no basic knowledge to know if this is the case

i presume so many possibilities on the drop-down come from the fact that this is some sort of ambiguous parameter

can anyone help me? any lecture of what i am doing at all?

Im adding some images of the case

cheers

Answer (score 1):

[From Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method)

> **HttpRequest.method**
>
> A string representing the HTTP method used in the request.
>   This is guaranteed to be uppercase.

It is initialized by Django framework reading from your actual HTTP request.

`QHttPRequestHeader.py` is coming from PyQT4 that has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: thank you, this makes total sense, but how come this HttpRequest doesn't show up on my right click>goto>definition   drop-down menu? i presume its cause its using the header i put on the question? can you tell me how to find the origin myself next time for when its not so easy to link to its origin? also i dont see how im linking to httprequest although i presume this happens since its a website after all, where can i see the place where this happens?

Comment: Look at the third one: *HttpRequest in django.http.request*

For the next time, please do not use pyCharm to understand, use the official documentation instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/

Comment: yes, totally, it is indeed there~ so many drop downs it gets confusing

Comment: i wouldnt have been able to find method just by documentation, word is too ambiguous

Comment: Just search in a smart way: "django request.method" gave me the link I wrote in the answer with at least two different search engines

Comment: request didnt give me any drop-down definition so i presumed its definition was when passed as an argument, thought this would mean .method a self.method call, however when i open method on 3rd drop down, request.py opens now

Comment: In your context `request` is just a variable, PyCharm is not always been able to understand what kind of object would be assigned to that variable.
Please, use PyCharm definitions dropdown only if you know what are you doing or what are you searching for. Remember that PyCharm will give you ALL the definition of such a name in **every** python library you installed.
If you wouldn't use a search engine, at least look for all and only the definition which start in `django.` (like `django.request.method`)